# Annotations without class import?

Tags: 8

The idea of annotations in Drupal 8 is that annotations names map to classes.
E.g. `@ViewsRow` -> `\Drupal\Views\Annotation\ViewsRow`.

From other code I have seen (Symfony, Doctrine), I assumed that to make this work, the annotation class needs to be imported, e.g.

```
use Drupal\Views\Annotation\ViewsRow;
```

However, this seems not to be the case for many of the plugin annotations e.g. in Views.

Why? Is this a Drupalism, or would we find the same in some places in Doctrine or Symfony? Is it good practice to omit the import?

In the past I disliked the need for such use statements, because they would show up in the IDE as "unused import". However, now I am using the annotation plugin in PhpStorm, so now it recognizes those imports.

Comment: of interest: https://www.drupal.org/node/2689243

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Drupal's annotation system is based on the [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) PHP library, and not on Symfony like the rest of Drupal.

Doctrine uses a [global annotation registry](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-common/en/latest/reference/annotations.html#introduction) to map classes to files (rather than an autoloader). [This page](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!core.api.php/group/annotation/8.2.x) contains the list of classes in that registry.

[This issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2090353) from 2013 shows the Drupal maintainers' decision to remove the need to import annotation classes.

You wouldn't know this by looking at the [official Drupal documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/2096117) -- they say the annotation classes are loaded "magically".

Comment: Thanks! This is the kind of background information I was looking for.

Comment: I think I remember a discussion somewhere, perhaps in php-fig where people discuss to require annotations being namespaced. Does this sound familiar?

Comment: Isn't Symfony using Doctrine components for its annotation parsing?

Comment: @donquixote I don't follow php-fig, so I'm not sure. And according to https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html, looks like Doctrine is decoupled and optional but still included in Symfony.